# Android - ListView not updating barprogress (sometimes)

Tags: android, listview

I have an xml layout which I use for each row in my listview:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
        android:background="@drawable/userchallenge_layout_border"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bar_reached"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
        android:background="@drawable/userchallenge_layout_border_progress"/>
```

The background is a drawable I made myself in an xml file, with color, strokes and such.
I have a list of users in my listview, and each user has a value, and I want to draw the as a progress how far each user has reached in the challenge. This is how I calculate it and draw it in my listview:

```
            TextView userName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            userName.setTypeface(tf);
            userName.setText(uc.getUser().getFullName());

            TextView totalBar = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar);
            final int totalBarWidth = totalBar.getWidth();

            TextView percent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.percent);
            percent.setTypeface(tf);
            percent.setText(oneDigit.format((uc.getValue()/challenge.getGoal()) * 100) + " %");

            TextView reachedBar = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bar_reached);
            reachedBar.setWidth((int) ((uc.getValue()/challenge.getGoal()) * totalBarWidth));
```

I get the right calculation, but my TextView (bar_reached) sometimes sets the width and sometimes it doesn't, I know that listviews redraws each time for each row, but I don't know how to solve this problem!

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a `List<Float> progressList` of progress and load data from it `progressList.get(position)` when [getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method is called . When progress changed save it `progressList.get(position) = newProgress`

By the way why just not to use [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)?

Comment: Is it better to use the progressbar? Could you please give an short example of implementing this progressbar? Think that would be alot better actually..

Comment: You can find a lot of tut using google, here is official android tutorial http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html Please mark as resolved, if you got your answer.